# Include delimiter in token when using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, regex-lookarounds

I want to use Java Scanner object to read file line "blocks" into objects.  The delimiter needs to be included in token.  I tried using regex lookbehind, but delimitter is variable length.  Does anyone have suggestions or alternatives for getting the delimiter?

Java code I currently have (which erroneously removes the "Processed Value" line):

```
ArrayList<ProcessedData> stack = new ArrayList<ProcessedData>();    

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/user/data.txt"));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Processed Value.+?\\n+", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
scanner.useDelimiter(pattern);

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    stack.add(new ProcessedData(scanner.next()));
}
```

Example file:

```
Id: 1
Raw Value: 1234
Processed Value{423}: A3s2344

Id: 36
Raw Value: 389001
Processed Value{2}: "Access Success"

Id: 28934
Raw Value: 2402
Processed Value: 1345.2 seconds
```

Comment: And what do you want to capture?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to know what is putting the line breaks in.  \n, \r, or something else?

Comment: I want to create 3 "ProcessedData" objects each containing an Id, a Raw Value, and a Processed Value.  So I want to capture and pass a 3 line string starting at "Id:" to the end of the "Processed Value" line.

Comment: @Andrew I'm pulling from the file.  Not writing to it.  File currently exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have one empty line between informations you need so maybe try to split your data on that empty line. You can try with this delimiter

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\r?\n){2,}");
scanner.useDelimiter(pattern);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/c6sR5A)

Comment: @TryThis what do you mean by "misses the last record"? If you see result in my demo it finds `Id: 28934
Raw Value: 2402
Processed Value: 1345.2 seconds`.

Comment: My bad.  Had assumed it would miss it as there is not a double space at the end.  Why does this work?

Comment: @TryThis You can think of delimiter as place where string should be split. It works this way because `next()` returns token that has either delimiter, or end of String after it. So `a{demimiter}b` will be split into `a` and `b` even if there is no `{delimiter}` after `b` (but there is end of String).

Comment: This answer is a solution to my underlying problem.  Thanks!  I'm still interested in if there is a solution to the title issue.  I'll accept this answer if the original question isn't answered over the next several days.

Comment: @TryThis To answer your title question: it would depends if you want to include delimiter at start or end of token. If at start then you can use look-ahead `(?=delimiter)`, if at the end then you have to use look-behind `(?<=delimiter)` but in this case you would need to set up maximal length of delimiter so in your case you can use something like `Pattern.compile("(?<=Processed Value.{1,1000}?)\r?\n");` - I assume that `\r\n` should be excluded from token, if not then move closing parenthesis at end of regex.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo.  Before I had posted the question I had implemented the maximum length lookback as described in your last comment.  It definately worked.  However the performance was quite poor, so I didn't end up going with it.  Additional info should probably help someone eventually though. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead in your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=Processed Value.+?\\n+)", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about this.  Just tried it.  Unfortunately with the Scanner class it is still removing the delimitter (same as it does with my original code from question).  So only the Id and Raw Value lines are captured.

Comment: That's not correct as I have tested myself and it does show `Processed Value` lines also in output.

Comment: When I copy and paste the pattern, the Processed Value doesn't appear with the correct record.  Meaning, the first record doesn't have a Processed Value, the second record has the first's Processed Value, etc.